# How to set a text field up with c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, storyboard, user-input

I am creating an ios app and in visual studio using storyboard. I have created a text field and I want to let the userName = what ever the user inputs. I am using c#.

Comment: I think there might be an error in line 42. 


Please provide some code and more details what you want to achieve, so we can help you.

Comment: We are going to need more than just a vague explanation of your problem. Post some **code, perhaps?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a textbox to achieve the user inputting.

Like the following:

```
string username = textBox1.Text;
```

If you want to know more about how it work in an ios app, you can refer to [Hello, iOS – Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/hello-ios/hello-ios-quickstart?pivots=windows).